# WPF listbox OO data template

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate

This is a basic question but I'm just coming back to WPF after a long break and can't remember how to do this. I've tried looking around but can't find exactly the answer I'm looking for.

I have a Listbox control that I want to bind to a `List<TradeViewModel>` collection. I want the `ListBoxItems` to pick up that the items are of type `TradeViewModel` and based on that, to use a custom data template including a checkbox that is bound to `TradeViewModel.IsChecked` and for the text of the row to be `TradeViewModel.TradeId`.

I have created the ViewModel class with exposed dependency properties and `INotifyPropertyChanged` but it's how to hook up the XAML and data templates that I can't quite remember how to do.

Can someone please help me with a quick example?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using mvvm light..

Comment: Here is a great MVVM and DataBinding sample http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200902MVVM this should bring back quite a few aspects of WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Grid> <!-- Or whatever -->
              <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
              <!-- Other UI Elements here -->
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```